# Fastest way to search a table of addresses in C++

Tags: c++, search, embedded, memory-address

Just an overview of what I am doing. I'm working with embedded systems and I don't use any dynamic memory.

As my program is running it will try and write to addresses in flash memory. Some of these addresses however will be mapped to other addresses. I have a table containing the addresses which should be mapped. Therefore before writing to an address, I need to check if this address is located in this table and if so, return the new mapped address.

I can simply iterate through the table from the beginning to end with a loop to check if the address is there but I am wondering if there is there a faster algorithm to do this? Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: binay search (if the table is sorted)?

Comment: A hash table of some sort? Perhaps using closed hashing to avoid dynamic allocation, if you know the expected number of entries in the table.

Comment: Unfortunately the table can't be sorted. Each entry will contain random memory addresses at an index which will be used to index to the new memory

Comment: Sorting isn't special - if a table can't be sorted, no other order can be assumed either. Then it's trivial to prove that the entries are unrelated, and any search has to be O(N). And this is easiest achieved by a linear search starting at location 0. of course, in embedded systems you should check if a "last element cache"  makes sense. Do you often get multiple requests in a row for the same address?

Comment: What's your definition of an "embedded system", since you use dynamic allocation in the first place? Please [read this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to dynamic memory (so no heap at all) then your best chances are related to have this table sorted so that you can do a fast lookup in *`O(log(n))`* through [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

If the table doesn't change too often and you don't need to resort it continuously then improvements should be significant.

Otherwise you should look into using a tree (to have *`O(log(n))`*) or and hash-map like structure which could reach *`O(1)`* but it really depends on your pattern of utilization of such data:

- does the table need to be dynamic
- how often you change it
- how often you search for value
- how large is it on the average case

Using a tree or an hash-map could be more tricky if you don't have access to dynamic memory though.

Comment: Have you got the use of [bsearch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/) ?

Comment: The table will have 128 uint32_t address entries. The memory location right after the table will be the actual new mapped memory. Each entry in the table will have random addresses and so I need the index in the table to index to the new memory location. I could do a sort every time I put in a new entry , but this would then involve copying and re-writing to memory. This could be faster in the long run but hard to tell

Comment: If each entry is a reasonably "random" address as you state, you can just use the bottom bits shifted as necessary (probably 2 or 3 shifts) to typical memory boundaries. Truncate and use as a hash function. I love embedded system programming but the details depend on many unstated conditions such as worst case v average access times and frequency if table updates v lookups.